# changing the background of textview in listview depending on the status of item

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` and in each row a `TextView` and a `CheckBox`.
Items in list are populated from database.
What I want to do is change the background of `TextView` in specific row depending on `CheckBox` status. If `CheckBox` is checked change background of `TextView`.
Is there a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

use `getView()` in your adapter  to do this it  returns the row that has to be drawn. This is the method we're interested in the most. It will be called every time the ListView draws a new row.
Here, you can control what gets drawn in a particular row, by selecting a layout and setting data into it.

see this [tutorial](http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-tutorial-custom-adapter-for.html)

Comment: can you give me an example? am new in android development

Comment: oups, i didnt se the link. I will look into it now

Answer (score 0):

add to adapter to method `getView()` your functional.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the onClickListener of the CheckBox while creating your Activity, and change the background inside the onClick mehod

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk);
chk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        if (chk.isChecked()){
            //Checked bg
        } else {
            //Unchecked bg
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It does the work, it changes the background as i want it to, but the problem is when application(or activity) is closed and reopened it needs to be clicked again to apply the background again, but  i need it to stay changed

Comment: try to save your states in SaredPreferences, for example.